# Eclipse GWT "Use Google Web Toolkit" keeps getting unchecked

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have a GWT project and I have been using it for a while now. Recently I ran into an issue where Eclipse said that my project is not a GWT project so I couldn't compile it. I checked the "Use Google Web Toolkit" and started using my project again. Since that first time, it has happened to me multiple times.

How can I get this checkbox to STAY checked?

I am using Eclipse version 3.8 and Google Suite Plugin 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

the `.classpath` file in your project's directory is modified when you set the "Use GWT" option. I am guessing that file keeps getting modified somehow. Do you have a version control system like SVN or git that might be reverting that file or updating it from the repository?

Comment: The file is not checked in to the repo, so it shouldn't be affected by subclipse (the svn plugin being used)